Gradient of Loss Function
The goal is to derive backwards propagation:
Note my Step name could be improper but these are the names I think they are...
\begin{align}
z_1&=W_1x_1+b_1\\
a_1&=\mathrm{RELU(z_1)}\\
z_2&=W_2a_1+b_2\\
\hat{y}&=\sigma(z_2)\\
L_{BCE}&=\frac{1}n\sum_\limits{i=1}^n(y_i\cdot \log(\hat{y}_i)+(1-y_i)\log(1-\hat{y}))
\end{align}
This is my methodology for solving the problem for my neural network backwards propagation.
Step 1
Binary Cross Entropy Partial $\frac{\delta L}{\delta \hat{y}}$
$$\frac{1}n\sum_\limits{i=1}^n(\frac{y_i}{\hat{y_i}}-\frac{(1-y_i)}{(1-\hat{y})}$$
$$\frac{\delta L}{\delta \hat{y}}=\frac{1}n\sum_\limits{i=1}^n(\frac{y_i(1-\hat{y})-\hat{y}(1-y_i)}{\hat{y}(1-\hat{y})})$$
Step 2
Partial of last activation layer $\frac{\delta \hat{y}}{\delta z_2}$
$$\sigma(z_2)(1-\sigma(z_2))$$
$$\frac{\delta \hat{y}}{\delta z_2}=\sigma(z_2)(1-\sigma(z_2))$$
Step 3
Partial of last input layer $\frac{\delta z_2}{\delta a_1}$
$$W_2$$
$$\frac{\delta z_2}{\delta a_1}=W_2$$
Step 4
Partial of first activation layer $\frac{\delta a_1}{\delta z_1}$
$$
\begin{cases}
0,  &  x\le 0\\
z_1, & x\gt 0 
\end{cases}$$
$$\frac{\delta a_1}{\delta z_1} =
\begin{cases}
0,  &  x\le 0\\
z_1, & x\gt 0 
\end{cases}$$
Step 5
Partial of first activation layer $\frac{\delta z_1}{\delta W_1}$
$$x_1$$
$$\frac{\delta z_1}{\delta W_1}= x_1$$
Now I believe I would multiply all the chains together and get the final result? Are there any mistakes and what would the final solution look like?
